# Insert key in default dict to the front

Tags: python

I have this defaultdict and a string variable:

```
my_dict = defaultdict(<class 'str'>, {2: 'bear', 3: 'fish', 4: 'dog', 5: 'goat'})

str_match = "goat"
```

and I would like to pop the key in `my_dict` which has the same value as `str_match`, and insert it at the front. Something like this:

```
my_dict = defaultdict(<class 'str'>, {5: 'goat', 2: 'bear', 3: 'fish', 4: 'dog'})
```

So far I have:

```
for key, value in list(my_dict.items()):
    if value == str_match:
        my_dict.pop(key)
```

Is there a way I can accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean _at the front_? Dictionaries **are not** ordered.

Comment: Not with a dictionary - 'at the front' is meaningless as dictionaries are not ordered. The pair 'at the front' may not be in the same place the next time you access the dictionary.

Comment: Python 3.2 introduced a `move_to_end` method that lets you move a key to the start or end of the sequence of keys. (Keys are otherwise ordered by their insertion order; they cannot be arbitrarily sorted.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the OrderedDict in python 2.7 or above. The link of Documentation is: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict